# CSS multi-button can't get correct positioning

Tags: html, css, web-frontend

I can't get the right positioning for two buttons in CSS.

The picture below details what my desired result looks like, but I need help with the positioning relative to the textarea above.
[desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MJKKS.png)

I have tried using absolute, relative, and flexbox positioning, but I am new and can't figure out how to make it work exactly as I need it.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you wanted?

```css
.comment-area {
  width: min-content;
}

.button-area {
  display: flex;
  gap: 4px;
}

.button-area > * {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="comment-area">
  <textarea></textarea>
  <div class="button-area">
    <button>Clear</button>
    <button>Submit</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: [current result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RbuJJ.png)
The button overshoots the box here when using this.

Comment: @lockcbah It seems the width of the container is not restricted to `min-content`. Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we could diagnosis what went wrong.

Comment: I forgot to mention that resizing is off, which is the problem. How do I fix it while still having resizing off?